# Straddle Checkboard Cipher decryption, list operation

Tags: python

What I want to do is convert a string like:

```
    "77 65 84"
```

To a list like:

```
    ["77", "65", "84"]
```

I tried the list() function but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `split()` method of strings.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`

```
test_str = "77 65 84"
test_list = test_str.split()

for i in test_list:
  print(i)
```

So after `.split()` `test_list[0]=77`  ,  `test_list[1]=65`  etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use split()

```
>>> my_string = "77 65 84"
>>> my_list = my_string.split()
>>> my_list
['77', '65', '84']
```

You can do the same thing by specifying the separator, like so:

```
>>> comma_string = "74,65,84"
>>> comma_list = comma_string.split(",")
>>> comma_list
['74', '65', '84']
```